# Joining tables based on on most recent date

Tags: postgresql, join

Let's say I have three tables:

- `employees`, with columns `id`, and `name`
- `salaries`, with columns `employee_id`, `salary`, `date`
- `underlings`, with columns `employee_id`, `number_of_underlings`, `date`

I want to join the tables such that for every `salaries` entry there is a row with the `salary` value, the `name` associated with that row's `employee_id`, and the `number_of_underlings` value whose row's `date` *most recently precedes* the `date` of the `salaries` entry (i.e., the number of underlings the given employee would have had at the time they had the given salary).

For example, assume the following rows appear in the described tables:

```
id | name      employee_id | salary  |    date         employee_id | number_of_underlings |    date
---+-------   -------------+---------+------------    -------------+----------------------+------------
13 | Sally              13 |   90000 | 2017-11-29               13 |                    0 | 2017-05-13
                        13 |   95000 | 2018-01-01               13 |                    6 | 2018-02-20
                        13 |  120000 | 2018-03-01
```

Then the resulting join would have rows:

```
 name  | salary  | number_of_underlings |    date
-------+---------+----------------------+------------
 Sally |   90000 |                    0 | 2017-11-29
 Sally |   95000 |                    0 | 2018-01-01
 Sally |  120000 |                    6 | 2018-03-01
```

Of course, joining the `employees` and `salaries` tables is trivial, but what about the `underlings` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    e.name,
    s.salary,
    (SELECT u.number_of_underlings FROM underlings u
     WHERE e.id = u.employee_id AND s.date >= u.date
     ORDER BY u.date DESC LIMIT 1) number_of_underlings,
    s.date
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN salaries s
    ON e.id = s.employee_id
```

### Demo

Comment: Awesome! I'm relatively new to SQL and had no idea that was a thing

Comment: @Wmbuch There might also be a way to write your query without using a correlated subquery.  I cannot see a way off the top of my head.